# Iterating through objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm am by no means an expert on javascript and trying to learn.

I've created a simple piece of code that adds a person object and displays it in HTML with some poorly formated strings. As i have two persons (p1 and p2) i would like to have them both added to the div "output". The idea is to create a list of each person object and place the properties in the list items.

My question is - how do i display each person object by iteration?

Thank you

```
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>

    <script>
      function person (fname, lname, age, birth)
      {
        this.firstname = fname;
        this.lastname = lname;
        this.age = age;
        this.birth = birth;
      }

      var p1 = new person("John", "Dhoe", 22,  new Date("December 13, 1973 11:13:00").toLocaleDateString());
      var p2 = new person("Mr", "Andersson", 56,  new Date("October 14, 1968 11:13:00").toLocaleDateString());

      p1.birthdate = function () {
        return "<ul>" + 
                  "<li>" + "<b>Name: </b>" + this.firstname + " " + this.lastname + "</li>" +
                  "<li>" + "<b>Age: </b>" + this.age + "</li>" +
                  "<li>"+ "<b>Birthdate: </b>" +  this.birth + "</li>" +
                "</ul>";
      }

      output.innerHTML = p1.birthdate();

    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: So, whats the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may do it like this.

We extend `person` with method that returns html presentation of data. It is available to each new `person` created so both `p1` and `p2` can use it. 
We output data manually with `p1.birthdate()` and `p2.birthdate()`. But if we need many `persons` to deal with we'd like to store `persons` into some array and then iterate through it.

```js
var persons = [];
function person (fname, lname, age, birth) {
  this.firstname = fname;
  this.lastname = lname;
  this.age = age;
  this.birth = birth;
}
person.prototype.birthdate = function () {
  var html = '';
  html += "<ul>" + 
                  "<li>" + "<b>Name: </b>" + this.firstname + " " + this.lastname + "</li>" +
                  "<li>" + "<b>Age: </b>" + this.age + "</li>" +
                  "<li>"+ "<b>Birthdate: </b>" +  this.birth + "</li>" +
                "</ul>";
  
  return html;
}
persons.push(new person("John", "Dhoe", 22,  new Date("December 13, 1973 11:13:00").toLocaleDateString()));
persons.push(new person("Mr", "Andersson", 56,  new Date("October 14, 1968 11:13:00").toLocaleDateString()));


var output = document.getElementById('output');

for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  output.innerHTML += persons[i].birthdate();
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: This actually makes lot of sence and easily understandable. Thank you!

Comment: I edited snippet above, so now all `person`s are stored in an array. Output-block then is filled via loop through that array.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an array of persons, then iterate over that array. Try something like this:

```
var persons = [
    new person("John", "Dhoe", 22,  new Date("December 13, 1973 11:13:00").toLocaleDateString()),
    new person("Mr", "Andersson", 56,  new Date("October 14, 1968 11:13:00").toLocaleDateString())
]; // An array of persons...

var html = '';
for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++){ // Iterate over all persons
    html += persons[i].birthdate();      // And add the HTML for each person to `html`
}
output.innerHTML = html;                 // Finally, add the persons html to the output.
```

Comment: Should have figured that one out.. Thanks

Comment: be advised though that you need to put the `birthdate` function into your object though as you can see in the fiddle that i posted in my answer

Answer (score -1):

Put the `birthdate` function into your `person` function. Then put all people into an array and call the function for each of them

```
for (var i= 0; i< people.length; i++){
    var output = document.getElementById("output");  
    output.innerHTML =  output.innerHTML + people[i].birthdate();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v9katu8z/

Comment: Don't modify the `innerHTML` on every iteration of the loop.